# How to print the image size after Pooling layer in a Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: theano, keras, conv-neural-network

I am creating a CNN in python using theano and keras. I want just to print the image size after Convolutional layer and Pooling layer using python. I use cifar10 dataset which is (3, 32, 32) and I want to know how much the image size get reduced.

```
image = X_train[1]
print(image.shape)
```

Using Theano backend.

```
(3, 32, 32)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Sequential() model you can do model.summary() after inserting that layer.

If you're using the functional API, you can create a model

```
keras.models.Model(input=my_input_layer,output=my_last_layer).summary()
```

does that help?

Comment: I would like to ask again about an issue that I am seeing the model.summary(). I am using a conv2d into cifar10 dataset with a kernel of 3*3 and 32 feature map, the out shouldn't image size be ((32-3)+1)/1 = 30*30 the output image? and I see from the summary that the output is 32,32,32

Comment: It depends on the border_mode argument in your convolution layer

Comment: border_mode='same' I should to change to?

Comment: This means that your image will be padded on the edges to make the output have the same shape as the input. If you dont want that, change to 'valid' which is the default. Does the my answer fix your problem?

Comment: Yes it's working the image size change, thank you  very much

Comment: Great, can you validate the answer then please? :)